# What is the most efficient way to compare 45 Million rows of Text File to about 200k rows text file and produce non matches from the smaller file?

Tags: python, pandas, iteration, large-files

I have a 45 million row txt file that contains hashes. What would be the most efficient way to compare the file to another file, and provide only items from the second file that are not in the large txt file?

Current working:

```
comm -13 largefile.txt smallfile.txt >> newfile.txt
```

This works pretty fast but I am looking to push this into python to run regardless of os?

Attempted with memory issues:

```
tp = pd.read_csv(r'./large file.txt',encoding='iso-8859-1', iterator=True, chunksize=50000)
full = pd.concat(tp, ignore_index=True)`
```

This method taps me out in memory usage and generally faults for some reason.

Example:

```
<large file.txt>
hashes
fffca07998354fc790f0f99a1bbfb241
fffca07998354fc790f0f99a1bbfb242
fffca07998354fc790f0f99a1bbfb243
fffca07998354fc790f0f99a1bbfb244
fffca07998354fc790f0f99a1bbfb245
fffca07998354fc790f0f99a1bbfb246


<smaller file.txt>
hashes
fffca07998354fc790f0f99a1bbfb245
fffca07998354fc790f0f99a1bbfb246
fffca07998354fc790f0f99a1bbfb247
fffca07998354fc790f0f99a1bbfb248
fffca07998354fc790f0f99a1bbfb249
fffca07998354fc790f0f99a1bbfb240
```

Expected Output

```
<new file.txt>
hashes
fffca07998354fc790f0f99a1bbfb247
fffca07998354fc790f0f99a1bbfb248
fffca07998354fc790f0f99a1bbfb249
fffca07998354fc790f0f99a1bbfb240
```

Comment: Read the pandas docs. Especially read_csv and join.

Comment: I wonder if Numpy is the way to go here.  Might take up less memory than Pandas?  Since Large and Smaller are different sizes, I don't believe you can leverage indexing.  Try `import numpy as np
la = np.loadtxt('large_file.txt', dtype='object')
sa = np.loadtxt('smaller_file.txt', dtype='object')
np.setdiff1d(sa, la)`  Get rid of any column headers first.  Also, you can set `assume_unique=True` in [setdiff1](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) if thats the case.  Should speed it up

Comment: This method took twice as long as the method to parse with comm. thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer ended up being an idiot check that should have been conducted well before I posted.

I was running 32 bit python in my IDE versus 64 bit due to a reinstall I had to conduct. After conducting this change, all worked well with loading the file in all at once and running a concat and drop duplicates on the dataframe. I appreciate all your answers and the input and help you gave. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hash table.  Or in Python terms, just use a `set`.

Put each item from the ***smaller*** file into the set.  200K items is perfectly fine.  Enumerate each item in the larger file to see if it exists in the smaller file.  If there is a match, remove the item from the the hash table.

When you are done, any item remaining in the set represents an item not found in the larger file.

My Python is a little rusty, but it would go something like this:

```
s = set()

with open("small_file.txt") as f:
     content = f.readlines()

for line in content:
    line = line.strip()
    s.add(line)

with open("large_file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
         if line in s:
            s.discard(line.strip())

for i in s:
    print(i)
```

Comment: You can simplify to eg `s = set(line.strip() for line in open("small_file.txt").readlines())`  and you don't need to test before calling `s.discard`

Comment: Both the comment from @donkopotamus and the original answer work well.

Comment: @johnnyb Out of curiosity, how long did this take compared to your original process?

Comment: The set method took approximately 3 minutes to produce the comm method took around 5! I will be able to time it later today!

Comment: After testing and troubleshooting, I found that this wasnt working as intended. I have added a matching item in both files and it was not discarded as the set.discard method states it should be! Any other suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested, but I think this would be non memory intensive (no idea on speed):

```
unique = []

with open('large_file.txt') as lf, open('small_file.txt') as sf:
    for small_line in sf:
        for large_line in lf:
            if small_line == large_line:
                break
        else:
            unique.append(small_line)
        lf.seek(0)
```